# PyQt4 - QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt, kde-plasma

After the last update of Manjaro Linux, something weird happened to my PyQt4. Qt otherwise (judging by working KDE workspace) works fine. Since many of my apps have their GUIs written in PyQt4, it is a huge issue for me. When I launch the app, I get random black spots instead of the widgets. My console is flooded by error messages:

This one is yielded on the start of the app:

```
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment.
```

And this one occurs every time the PaintEvent is called:

```
X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
Major opcode: 56 (X_ChangeGC)
Resource id:  0x0

X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x0
```

I tried all the stuff reccommended on the first few pages of Google. Stuff which is not working for me:

- setting lodas of the `QT_*` session variables
- adding some stuff to the `sysctl` in order to increase the memory for Qt, although I am absolutely sure it has enough (or it could have enough if some bug does not allow it to take it itself)
- reinstalling the Python bindings for Qt

The most weird thing is that this occurs after about 10 minutes of working with Qt, then I have to restart the service which handles my workspace.

Anyone managed to solve this before?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you asking here? This is obviously not a programming-related problem. You should be reporting bugs like this to the maintainers of Manjaro.

Comment: I think this should be reported to maintainers of Qt, since as seen on Google, many people have this issue, not only pythoners and users of Manjaro. The bug has been reported many times and none of the suggested solutions is working. Thus, I am trying to ask here to get another possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, as I said: it's not a **programming-related** problem, and is therefore off-topic for SO. For you, it was specifically caused by a Manjaro update, and so that is where you should look for answers. (Presumably, if you undo the update, the problem will go away).

Comment: Well, maybe it is not a _directly_ programming-related problem, it could get a much better treatment on http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Yesterday I updated my Qt installation too, and now it's broken *system-wide* in exactly the same way as yours. Some time after reboot the all new windows render incorrectly and throw the same error message as yours in the terminal. Please leave a post here if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to problem with openjdk version 7u85-2.6.1 that has been affecting Ubuntu and Arch users.
Ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1511395

Arch:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200372

It seems like an old bug that made a re-appearance in the latest patch, so you might try rolling back the update.